# Looking for developer advice for a git environment using docker

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am running across this problem on a project of mine and was wondering if anyone had a solution. We have several applications stored on their own gitlab repository. You can run them simultaneously on the same local machine because they all listen on different ports.

We have dockerized this environment for easier startup and image use. There are slight changes you need to make to the applications because instead of using localhost for configuration we have to specify the docker container name to utilize the dns resolution within the docker network. So each application has a minor change (one file) in order to work as a docker compose.

We have a repository dedicated to storing the docker-compose.yml and the applications (as submodules).
This repository looks something like this:

```
docker-compose.yml
applications/
    submodule1
    submodule2
...
```

Currently these submodules are confiured to point to specific branches with the "small change" that I mentioned above. The problem is that these branches can never be merged, they always have to live on the repository and constantly rebase for incoming changes. This allows the repo to work right out of the box

I am curious if there is a better way to build my docker compose environment without having these branches live on the repository for eternity or if someone else has encountered this problem and has any other suggestions. I guess a solution would be to not use these branches and make the configuration changes locally on the submodules...however when developers go to push I know they are going to forget and end up commiting these unwanted changes to the original repos.

Answer (score 1):

These host names will be different in every environment you deploy to.  Consider a potential deployment scenario where you deploy each service to a separate VM; then the host names will be those VMs' DNS names.  Or, consider deploying to Kubernetes; then you will need `service.namespace.svc.cluster.local`.

Correspondingly, you really shouldn't check host names like this into your source tree.  You'll need "one little change" like this for every service in every environment, not just "local" vs. "Compose".

Environment variables are a convenient approach for this in most container environments.  It tends to be easy to set an environment variable when you run a container, for example through Compose `environment:`.  You can usually set a default value for an environment variable in your code.  I've found it helpful to set these default values to what a developer would use, and assume every "real" deployment scenario will set the environment variables in a different way.

Let's say you have a `foo-service` that normally listens for HTTP on port 12345.  An environment variable will have its location.  Using Python as an example:

```py
foo_service_url = os.environ.get('FOO_SERVICE_URL', 'http://localhost:12345')
requests.get(foo_service_url + '/api/x')
```

Now you can just run this locally as a developer, and get that `localhost` address.  But if you want to run it in Compose, the host names will be different, and you can set the URLs accordingly

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  foo:
    build: ./foo
  bar:
    build: ./bar
    environment:
      FOO_SERVICE_URL: http://foo:12345
```

Comment: Environmental variables! Thank you thats a great idea for the docker compose thank you.