# Change the database host in psycopg2.connect when starting Docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, psycopg2

I have app.py ('collect_weather.py') with func main().
When I launch app.py locally, everything works fine. But if I run docker-compose, then I get an error. Accessing with running containers psycopg2.connect(host='localhost') is an error because I have to access the database as the name of the container host='db'. But I want to use 'localhost' when running locally, and 'db' when running in a container without making changes to the code.
Links: "db:localhost" doesn't work for some reason.

Maybe you will see the problem...

```
from backend.settings import DATABASES
HOST = DATABASES['default']['HOST']

def main():
    con = psycopg2.connect(
        user='postgres',
        password='password',
        host=HOST,
        database=DB_PATH)
```

DATABASES settings:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'pg_db_weather',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'PORT': 5432,
```

.env

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=pg_db_weather
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

CMD ["python", "/app/collect_weather.py"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '2.18'

volumes:
  pg_db_weather:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.10
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./pg_db_weather:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  backend:
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    links:
      - "db:localhost"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Error:

```
...
backend-backend-1  |     con = psycopg2.connect(
backend-backend-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
backend-backend-1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
backend-backend-1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
backend-backend-1  |    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
backend-backend-1  | connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
backend-backend-1  |    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
backend-backend-1  |
backend-backend-1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: I talk about environment variables as an approach for this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77131151/10008173), even with a Python example; will a setup like that work for you?

Comment: It doesn't work for me, because psycopg2.connect(host=HOST) takes a variable from .env

Answer (score 0):

I found the idea for my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878953/how-does-one-detect-if-one-is-running-within-a-docker-container-within-python).

In Dockerfile added:

```
ENV HOST=db
```

In app.py added:

```
import os

CONTAINER_HOST = os.environ.get('HOST')

if CONTAINER_HOST:
    HOST = CONTAINER_HOST
```

So in my function `psycopg2.connect(host=HOST)` using HOST='localhost' from settings -> .env
But when the container starts function using HOST='db' from Dockerfile.